# Diode 'D2' specification and suitable replacement

Tags: diodes, joystick

I am referring to 'D2 - 3pin dual-diode (R5/IRQ7 to GND and R3/DAT to GND)' in the section 'Pinouts - Component List and Chipset Pin-Outs for Analog Joypad, SCPH-110' listed in PlayStation Specifications at
https://psx-spx.consoledev.net/pinouts/.

I am unable to figure out whether the diode D2 is of the 'common-anode', 'common-cathode' or 'serial' type.

What would be the suitable replacement for D2?

Please help.

Comment: As you say, it's hard to tell what's meant here. You have this PCB and troubleshoots it?

Comment: Yeah, I check out D2 component. if I test superior pin and some of two inferior pin, I get voltage in diode mode: no matter the position of the tips. But if I just test 2 inferior pins I don't get voltage.

Comment: Superior single pin is linked with ground

Comment: What package, and is there any number on the component? A photo edited into your questions would be good.

Answer (score 0):

```
   D2   3pin dual-diode (R5/IRQ7 to GND and R3/DAT to GND)
```

since all signals are presumably positive with respect to ground it would be common anode,  since one end is grounded it is not performing a logic function so probably ESD protrection instead,  making it some sort of dual zener or TVS.

eg: PESD2USB3UXT

Comment: I'm going to check PESD2USB3UXT datasheet